# Custom font on append text Richtextbox C#

Tags: c#, json, winforms, richtextbox

I'm trying to create an overload of my append text so I can customize text on every line but new Font() just "overwrites" (don't know the term, sorry) the lines.

```
    public void AppendThis(string text)
    {
        Preview.AppendText(text);
        Preview.AppendText("\n");
        Preview.ScrollToCaret();
    }

    public void AppendThis(string text, string font, float size)
    {
        Preview.Font = new Font(font, size);
        Preview.AppendText(text);
        Preview.AppendText("\n");
        Preview.ScrollToCaret();
    }

    public void AppendThis(string text, string font, float size, FontStyle style)
    {
        Preview.Font = new Font(font, size, style);
        Preview.AppendText(text);
        Preview.AppendText("\n");
        Preview.ScrollToCaret();
    }
```

I'm trying to display my text like this.

```
    public void DisplayPreview(string path)
    {
        string jsonfile = File.ReadAllText(path);
        Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(jsonfile);
        AppendThis(myDeserializedClass.basics.name, "Times New Roman", 20, FontStyle.Bold);
        AppendThis(myDeserializedClass.basics.email, "Arial", 20);
        AppendThis(myDeserializedClass.basics.location.address);
        AppendThis(myDeserializedClass.basics.location.postalCode);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `SelectionFont` property instead of `Font`.

```
    public void AppendThis(string text)
    {
        Preview.AppendText(text);
        Preview.AppendText("\n");
        Preview.ScrollToCaret();
    }

    public void AppendThis(string text, string font, float size)
    {
        Preview.SelectionFont = new Font(font, size);
        Preview.AppendText(text);
        Preview.AppendText("\n");
        Preview.ScrollToCaret();
    }

    public void AppendThis(string text, string font, float size, FontStyle style)
    {
        Preview.SelectionFont = new Font(font, size, style);
        Preview.AppendText(text);
        Preview.AppendText("\n");
        Preview.ScrollToCaret();
    }
```